# Select and unlink file on 3 tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, pdo

Please help me to check my query. I have search a lot and I have'nt try to select 3 tables before.

I think I got it right but I dont know why there's nothing happen.

```html
  public function delSection($delete_id)
  {
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM tbl_section
                                           JOIN tbl_login ON (tbl_login.sec_id = tbl_section.sec_id)
                                           JOIN tbl_content ON (tbl_content.sec_id = tbl_section.sec_id)
                                           WHERE tbl_section.sec_id=:del_id");
    $stmt->execute(array(":del_id"=>$delete_id));
    while($linkRow=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
    {
      unlink(__DIR__."/Admin/cover_images/".$linkRow['sec_cover']);
      unlink(__DIR__."/Admin/Files/".$linkRow['sec_id']."/".$linkRow['file_name']);
      rmdir(__DIR__."/Admin/Files/".$linkRow['sec_id']);
    }

    $stmt2 = $this->conn->prepare("DELETE tbl_section, tbl_login, tbl_content FROM tbl_section
                                          JOIN tbl_login ON (tbl_login.sec_id = tbl_section.sec_id)
                                          JOIN tbl_content ON (tbl_content.sec_id = tbl_section.sec_id)
                                          WHERE tbl_section.sec_id=:del_id");

    $stmt2->bindparam(":del_id",$delete_id);
    $stmt2->execute();
    return true;
  }
```

What I am trying to do is to select * from 3 tables and fetch their data with fk sec_id

here's the manual running of query

[image]

link:

[image]

Code:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: You have "table_files.sec_id" in the WHERE clause .... but I don't see it in the SELECT or JOINs, so I don't know what you're trying to do there. Also, what error are you getting? What happens when you run the select clause independently? Any reason you're using explicit joins, rather than simple joins?

Comment: I'll edit my post please have a second to take a look

Comment: "sec_id" column in two or more tables so you can use as  "tbl_section.sec_id" in where clause

Comment: no errors but I also do nothing

Comment: Table_files isn't in the select part of the query - so it makes no sense to have it in the join, AFAICS. The PHP code isn't relevant here, I think. Maybe just look at the SQL part - and determine exactly what it you're trying to do, and which tables you need in your query. You mention 4 tables, but the query is not well structured.

Comment: Yup I have notice it. now there is no error but it do nothing too.

Comment: did it delete????

Comment: No delete no unlink no error too

Comment: how about try manually running that query in your phpmyadmin with a sample correct parameter check it

Comment: Thank you I will try sir :)

Comment: Please take a look with my update

Comment: @McC0d3 so it does not have a result? thats why it does nothing?

Comment: @Beginner you got it

Comment: what should I do?

Comment: does the `sec_id = 18`  data exist in your table?

Comment: @Beginner Yes. I update my post again :) thanks

Comment: UPDATED T_T T_T T_T T_T

Comment: @McC0d3 i see your `tbl_content` has no data

Comment: yes but the other table have data. is it necessary to input data before deleting in 3 table?

Comment: There's nothing in tbl_content - so the join will produce nothing.

Comment: Yes. I use left join

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Done With LEFT OUTER JOIN QUERY

```html
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM tbl_section
                                           LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_login ON (tbl_login.sec_id = tbl_section.sec_id)
                                           LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_content ON (tbl_content.sec_id = tbl_section.sec_id)
                                           WHERE tbl_section.sec_id=:unlink_id");
```